# iBooks Author custom layout

Tags: books, ibooks-author

I'm looking to build an iBook with iBooks Author which would require a jQuery masonry-esque layout and I have scoured the web for documentation, help, tutorials, and articles that may help me embark on this project but to no avail. I know custom layouts are possible because [the project uses this iBook as a reference](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/learn-violin/id537493491?mt=11). Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction that may help me in this quest? I must first say that I'm a front-end developer by trade and I've never created an iBook before.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The layouts are all editable when using the graphical interface of iBooks Author. I don't see why you couldn't edit the files on the filesystem if you wanted to do advanced editing, but for most uses the GUI works well for my needs.

Start with a template you like and open it:

- **View** menu -> **Show Layouts**
- make your changes
- **File** menu -> **Save as Template...**